# Add container view to navigation controller

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, uicontainerview

I want to create a container view which has some views on it. I managed to get this working with Auto Layout. Now I want to place this container in a `UINavigationController`. I did this in the iOS Designer but the following code doesn't work anymore (it works without navigation controller):

```
HalfTableViewController testController1 = new HalfTableViewController ();
this.AddChildViewController (testController1);
testController1.View.Frame = View.Bounds;
this.View.AddSubview (testController1.View);
```

It's in C# but it shouldn't matter if you are not familiar with it. I want to know how I can use the view of the navigation controller as container view on which I can add my views. Currently, I see the navigation bar but the view is a black screen. I tried a few things but I don't know how can I get this working. Your solution can be of course in Objective-C.

**Edit:**

I tried it without AutoLayout and the table views are showing up. Now I want to know what I'm doing wrong. Here is my Auto Layout code:

```
View.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
tv1.View.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
tv2.View.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
tv3.View.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;

var constraints = new List<NSLayoutConstraint> ();
constraints.Add (NSLayoutConstraint.Create (tv1.View, NSLayoutAttribute.Top, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, TopLayoutGuide, NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, 1, 0));
constraints.Add (NSLayoutConstraint.Create (tv1.View, NSLayoutAttribute.Left, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, View, NSLayoutAttribute.Left, 1, 0));
constraints.Add (NSLayoutConstraint.Create (tv1.View, NSLayoutAttribute.Right, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, tv2.View, NSLayoutAttribute.Left, 1, 0));
constraints.Add (NSLayoutConstraint.Create (tv1.View, NSLayoutAttribute.Width, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, tv2.View, NSLayoutAttribute.Width, 1, 0));
constraints.Add (NSLayoutConstraint.Create (tv1.View, NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, View, NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, 1, 0));

constraints.Add (NSLayoutConstraint.Create (tv2.View, NSLayoutAttribute.Top, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, TopLayoutGuide, NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, 1, 0));
constraints.Add (NSLayoutConstraint.Create (tv2.View, NSLayoutAttribute.Left, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, tv1.View, NSLayoutAttribute.Right, 1, 0));
constraints.Add (NSLayoutConstraint.Create (tv2.View, NSLayoutAttribute.Right, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, tv3.View, NSLayoutAttribute.Left, 1, 0));
constraints.Add (NSLayoutConstraint.Create (tv2.View, NSLayoutAttribute.Width, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, tv3.View, NSLayoutAttribute.Width, 1, 0));
constraints.Add (NSLayoutConstraint.Create (tv2.View, NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, View, NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, 1, 0));

constraints.Add (NSLayoutConstraint.Create (tv3.View, NSLayoutAttribute.Top, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, TopLayoutGuide, NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, 1, 0));
constraints.Add (NSLayoutConstraint.Create (tv3.View, NSLayoutAttribute.Left, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, tv2.View, NSLayoutAttribute.Right, 1, 0));
constraints.Add (NSLayoutConstraint.Create (tv3.View, NSLayoutAttribute.Right, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, View, NSLayoutAttribute.Right, 1, 0));
constraints.Add (NSLayoutConstraint.Create (tv3.View, NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, View, NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, 1, 0));

View.AddConstraints (constraints.ToArray ());
```

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to do that trick:

```
//View.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
tv1.View.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
tv2.View.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
tv3.View.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;

var constraints = new List<NSLayoutConstraint> ();

constraints.Add (NSLayoutConstraint.Create (tv1.View, NSLayoutAttribute.Top, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, TopLayoutGuide, NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, 1, 0));
constraints.Add (NSLayoutConstraint.Create (tv1.View, NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, BottomLayoutGuide, NSLayoutAttribute.Top, 1, 0));
constraints.Add (NSLayoutConstraint.Create (tv1.View, NSLayoutAttribute.Left, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, View, NSLayoutAttribute.Left, 1, 0));
constraints.Add (NSLayoutConstraint.Create (tv1.View, NSLayoutAttribute.Right, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, tv2.View, NSLayoutAttribute.Left, 1, 0));

constraints.Add (NSLayoutConstraint.Create (tv2.View, NSLayoutAttribute.Top, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, TopLayoutGuide, NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, 1, 0));
constraints.Add (NSLayoutConstraint.Create (tv2.View, NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, BottomLayoutGuide, NSLayoutAttribute.Top, 1, 0));
constraints.Add (NSLayoutConstraint.Create (tv2.View, NSLayoutAttribute.Left, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, tv1.View, NSLayoutAttribute.Right, 1, 0));
constraints.Add (NSLayoutConstraint.Create (tv2.View, NSLayoutAttribute.Right, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, tv3.View, NSLayoutAttribute.Left, 1, 0));
constraints.Add (NSLayoutConstraint.Create (tv2.View, NSLayoutAttribute.Width, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, tv1.View, NSLayoutAttribute.Width, 1, 0));

constraints.Add (NSLayoutConstraint.Create (tv3.View, NSLayoutAttribute.Top, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, TopLayoutGuide, NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, 1, 0));
constraints.Add (NSLayoutConstraint.Create (tv3.View, NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, BottomLayoutGuide, NSLayoutAttribute.Top, 1, 0));
constraints.Add (NSLayoutConstraint.Create (tv3.View, NSLayoutAttribute.Left, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, tv2.View, NSLayoutAttribute.Right, 1, 0));
constraints.Add (NSLayoutConstraint.Create (tv3.View, NSLayoutAttribute.Right, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, View, NSLayoutAttribute.Right, 1, 0));
constraints.Add (NSLayoutConstraint.Create (tv3.View, NSLayoutAttribute.Width, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, tv1.View, NSLayoutAttribute.Width, 1, 0));
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you should know model view controller concept.

1. Here controller is Navigation controller which contains views which we will to and from.
2. model is the data
3. view controller holds view.

Code:

```
//Create a container view.
From above concept the below is view
TestViewController *testview = [[TestviewCopntroller alloc]init];
//set some properties

//the below is data
testview.somearray = array;
testview.somedictionary = dictionary;

//and this is navigation controller
UINavigationController *nav = [[UInavigationController alloc]initwithrootviewcontroller:testview];

//if you want this as root view then
appdelegate.window.rootviewcontroller = nav;

//if you want to present this view
[self presentviewcontroller:nav animated:YES];

//if you want to push
[self.navigationcontroller pushviewcontroller:testview animated:YES];
```

Comment: I know the MVC concept but that is not my problem here. I don't want to push a view here. I want to add a child view to my navigation controller (as it should be a `UIContainerView`). But I always get a black screen.

Comment: see u cannot add subview to navigation controller.have a view controller which is child of navigation controller and you can add container view to the child view controller.navigation controller view is what we see which is of height 45 or 60.why do u want to add uicontainerview to navigation controller.tell it clearly.

Comment: I want to have an advanced `UISplitViewController`. I want to place three table views side by side. The split view controller can only be the root view all the time. A container could be the solution to my problem (having different views on it). The `UINavigationController` should be used for navigation. Or do you have another idea?

Comment: check google for slidingview controller.It will have split view and first part is fixed and depending on first split selection you will have second and second table cell select gives third table.better search for some slidingview controller projects on github

Comment: Do you mean something like the `SWRevealController`? Or on which example have you thought? I need to display three table views at the same time (for iPad). Don't know if a sliding view controller would help here.

Comment: use can use some stack view controllers.